# React native jest: While resolving: image-jest@1.0.0 npm ERR! Found: react@17.0.1

Tags: react-native, testing, react-native-testing-library

I am trying to install [@testing-library/react-native](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@testing-library/react-native) to a freshly created expo-based react native application.

For adding test cases, I followed the steps mentioned in https://docs.expo.dev/guides/testing-with-jest/ and installed [jest](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jest) and [jest-expo](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jest-expo).

After that, I tried installing [@testing-library/react-native](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@testing-library/react-native) using command

```
npm install --save-dev @testing-library/react-native
```

and started getting the below error

```
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR!
npm ERR! While resolving: image-jest@1.0.0
npm ERR! Found: react@17.0.1
npm ERR! node_modules/react
npm ERR!   react@"17.0.1" from the root project
npm ERR!   peer react@">=16.0.0" from @testing-library/react-native@9.0.0
npm ERR!   node_modules/@testing-library/react-native
npm ERR!     dev @testing-library/react-native@"*" from the root project
npm ERR!   1 more (react-native)
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer react@"17.0.2" from react-test-renderer@17.0.2
npm ERR! node_modules/react-test-renderer
npm ERR!   peer react-test-renderer@">=16.0.0" from @testing-library/react-native@9.0.0
npm ERR!   node_modules/@testing-library/react-native
npm ERR!     dev @testing-library/react-native@"*" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
```

My `package.json` looks like below

```
{
  "name": "image-jest",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start",
    "android": "expo start --android",
    "ios": "expo start --ios",
    "web": "expo start --web",
    "eject": "expo eject",
    "test": "jest"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "expo": "~44.0.0",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.2.0",
    "react": "17.0.1",
    "react-dom": "17.0.1",
    "react-native": "0.64.3",
    "react-native-web": "0.17.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.12.9",
    "@types/jest": "^27.4.1",
    "@types/react": "~17.0.21",
    "@types/react-native": "~0.64.12",
    "jest": "^26.6.3",
    "jest-expo": "^44.0.1",
    "typescript": "~4.3.5"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "jest-expo",
    "transformIgnorePatterns": [
      "node_modules/(?!((jest-)?react-native|@react-native(-community)?)|expo(nent)?|@expo(nent)?/.*|@expo-google-fonts/.*|react-navigation|@react-navigation/.*|@unimodules/.*|unimodules|sentry-expo|native-base|react-native-svg)"
    ]
  },
  "private": true
}
```

I am unable to understand what is causing the issue. Can anyone suggest what can be done to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

The error is because the  *react-test-renderer@17.0.2*  requires *react@17.0.2*,
while you have an older version of react.

Try to install an older version of *react-test-renderer* first:

```
npm i react-test-renderer@17.0.1
```

And then install *@testing-library/react-native*